# Student project that calculates the return on an investment

Tags: java, homework, calculator, finance, javafx

This is a simple student project that calculates the return on an investment with a given investment amount, number of years invested, and annual interest rate.  I know this is pretty basic, but I'm just looking for feedback for formatting and other general improvements I can make to the code.

```
// Author: Joshua Ferrell
// Date: 3/25/2017

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

// A program that caculates the return on an investment.

public class Exercise15_5 extends Application {

    // globals
    private TextField tfInvestmentAmount = new TextField();
    private TextField tfNumYears = new TextField();
    private TextField tfAnnualInterestRate = new TextField();
    private TextField tfFutureValue = new TextField();
    private Button btCalc = new Button("Calculate");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create UI
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setVgap(5);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Investment Amount:"), 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(tfInvestmentAmount, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Number of Years:"), 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(tfNumYears, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Annual Interest Rate:"), 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(tfAnnualInterestRate, 1, 2);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Future Value:"), 0, 3);
        gridPane.add(tfFutureValue, 1, 3);
        gridPane.add(btCalc, 1, 4);

        // Set Properties for UI
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tfInvestmentAmount.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfNumYears.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfAnnualInterestRate.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfFutureValue.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfFutureValue.setEditable(false);
        gridPane.setHalignment(btCalc, HPos.RIGHT);

        // Process event (caculate future value)
        btCalc.setOnAction(e -> calculateFutureValue());

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane, 300, 200));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Exercise15_05"); // Set Title
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the Stage
    } 

    private void calculateFutureValue() {

        // Get Values from text fields
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(tfInvestmentAmount.getText());
        double interest = Double.parseDouble(tfAnnualInterestRate.getText());
        int years = Integer.parseInt(tfNumYears.getText());

        // Get Monthly interest rate
        double monthlyInterestRate = interest / 12 / 100;

        // Get Future Value
        double futureValue = amount * Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, years * 12);

        // set futureValue to tfFutureValue
        tfFutureValue.setText(String.format("$%.2f", futureValue));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that is noticeable when looking at this code is that there are too many **comments**. Let me explain.

#### Example 1 - stating the obvious

```
    // set futureValue to tfFutureValue
    tfFutureValue.setText(String.format("$%.2f", futureValue));
```

This comment does not add any value to your program, it creates mess. The code itself is self-explanatory, and even if I had 2 weeks experience in Java, I would know what it does.

#### Example 2 - stating the untrue

```
public class Exercise15_5 extends Application {

    // globals
    private TextField tfInvestmentAmount = new TextField();
    private TextField tfNumYears = new TextField();
    private TextField tfAnnualInterestRate = new TextField();
```

The comment that says `//globals` is simply wrong - the `TextField`s are private fields of `Exercise15_5` class. You can create a "global" variable in Java by creating a `public static` field - then you can use it everywhere, but of course you don't want to do that in your application

#### Example 3 - extract code to a method instead of commenting

In your `start()` method, you have 4 big blocks of code that are doing different things and are commented accordingly, like:

```
    // Set Properties for UI
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    tfInvestmentAmount.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfNumYears.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfAnnualInterestRate.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfFutureValue.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfFutureValue.setEditable(false);
    gridPane.setHalignment(btCalc, HPos.RIGHT);
```

We can extract those lines to a new method and give it some meaningful name... Just like we would comment those lines!

```
private void setPropertiesForUI() {
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    tfInvestmentAmount.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfNumYears.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfAnnualInterestRate.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfFutureValue.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
    tfFutureValue.setEditable(false);
    gridPane.setHalignment(btCalc, HPos.RIGHT);
}
```

Then, your `start()` method becomes much cleaner:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    createUI();
    setPropertiesForUI();
    calculateFutureValue();
    createSceneAndPlaceItInTheStage();
}
```

---

#### Split logic and UI into separate classes

I also believe that the `calculateFutureValue()` method should not be in the `Exercise15_5` class. It should be extracted to another class, possibly something named like `InvestmentCalculator`. The method should take doubles and int as input parameters, not `String`s (it doesn't know about textfields and UI).

You can make the `calculateFutureValue()` static in the `InvestmentCalculator` class since it's just performing some calculations and returning a value - you don't need an instance of it. You can even make `InvestmentCalculator`s constructor private to prevent creating an instance of it - in other words, making the `InvestmentCalculator` a [Util Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223553/how-can-i-create-an-utility-class).

I don't want to go into the implementation details since this is tagged as homework, but you can always edit your question or post another one after the refactoring.